# Why must the base and argument of a logarithm be positive?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

A counter-example (based on my misunderstanding) is, say, if $(-3)^3=-27$ then why is it not the case that $log_{-3}(-27)=3$?

Comment: The base of a logaritm is $a>0, a\neq 1$. In addition the argument is always $>0$.